# Why do server error codes start at 1xx and not at 0xx?

Tags: http, server-error

Why do server error codes start at 1xx and not at 0xx. I know 1xx, 2xx etc. have their own meaning, but why doesn't it start at 0xx ?

I read most of the [HTTP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) and browsed trough the [error codes](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) without any luck.

Comment: This approach is something of a defense against bad implementers.  Do you write out `50` or `050` for the relevant status code?  If it was `50`, is its first digit "5" or is it less than 100?  Just starting at 100 avoids these questions (which aren't hard, but they're still a source of bugs).

Answer (score 1):

According to the link that you provided:

"The first digit of the Status-Code defines the class of response. The last two digits do not have any categorization role. There are 5 values for the first digit"

There is no real reason for this and it's just a standard. As a design matter it's better to deal with fixed digits. The characters are fixed. It's  clear and easy to understand. Also it says that it must be 3 digits. having 0 for the first digit complicates things easily.

Comment: Thnx for your respondse !

Comment: Also it says that it must be 3 digits. having 0 for the first digit complicates things easily.

Comment: But they could start it from 0... same as other platforms like Windows, Linux etc... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Honestly, I don't think that there is any real reason! It just is. More information about the design standard can be find from: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6